# Flink broadcast function uses single parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-flink

I have one broadcast function in Flink that accepts two kinesis streams, one for the element A and one for broadcast element B. I noticed that all element A goes into one task slot even if I have already set the env parallelism to 4.

here is the main process function:

```
env.setParallelism(4);

BroadcastStream<ElementBroadcast> elementBroadcastStream =
    env.addSource(elementBroadcastSource)
        .uid("element-broadcast")
        .name("broadcast")
        .setParallelism(4)
        .returns(ElementB.class)
        .broadcast(Descriptors.ELEMENT_B_DESCRIPTORS);

DataStream<ElementA> elementAStream =
    elementASourceStream
        .connect(elementBroadcastStream)
        .process(injector.getInstance(
            ElementAElementBProcessFunction.class))
        .uid("");
```

The strange thing is when I check the Flink job or read the metrics I added inside the ElementAElementBProcessFunction, only the metrics in processBroadcastElement() confirms that all 4 task slots can received Element B, the processElement() works like a single thread function and you can also see it from the attached screenshots all the records(Element A) are received on slot 3. The other three slots receives 2 broadcast elements(Element B) from my application, but no element A at all.

Does any one know why multi slots parallelism only appears inside the processBroadcastElement() but not processElement()?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might because the partition of soucre A is 1, you can check it on your AWS Management Console or use rebalance or rescale before process. As for element B, you broadcast it, this guarantees that all elements go to all downstream tasks.

Comment: do you mean the provisioned shards on AWS management console? I do see it as 1 on that input stream

Comment: Yes, the provisioned shards is 1 so that only one subtask of source can get data. And you didn't shuffle before process, this is why only one subtaks can receive data. You can shuffle via rescale or rebalance before process. This should make the data goes to the other 3 subtasks.

Comment: thank you, and the reason that I do see element A got evenly distributed in later keyed process function is because it went through an keyBy() operation so it became available for each subtask, right?

Comment: Right. keyBy() do shuffle the elements, but it assigns the element with same key to the same partition.